# How can I generate multi-language documentation with typedoc?

Tags: typescript, documentation, typedoc

I'm looking for a way to support multiple languages ​​by writing typescript comments like this:

```
/**
 * @en english comment
 * @fr commentaire français
 *
 */
export class MyClass {}
```

For example, is there an idea that one of the comments @en and @fr is selected and output?
I tried to find typedoc, but there seems to be no such function.

Comment: Which documentation engine are you using (and which version)? In doxygen there are the commands `FindFileCacheElem` (see: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdtilde) and you probably have to use the setting `OUTPUT_LANGUAGE` (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_output_language) to get the generated headings / texts right. You specified `typescript` though doxygen doesn't really support `typescript`.

Comment: albert, thank you for your comment.

I have tried is typedoc and the versions are:
- typedoc : 0.23.17
- typescript : 4.8.4

Doxygen is a good tool, but as you said it doesn't support typescript, so I can't use it this time.

Comment: There is a [typedoc-plugin-localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-plugin-localization), I've never used it though, so can't speak to it's usefulness

Comment: Gerrit0, thank you for your information!
[typedoc-plugin-localization](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-plugin-localization) is seems like a good tool to solve multilingualization. 
I think this is certainly a candidate, but the specification is to prepare the code description in a separate json file.
If possible, I think it would make maintenance easier if I could add multilingual comments near the code.
Thanks for the idea though!